# Do apache_beam pipelines need to be declared using a with statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-beam, with-statement

I started learning apache beam, and while trying to build my very first pipeline (in python), I encountered a strange behavior.

Here are the elements of my code :

A file : `count_words.txt` containing:

```
Strawberry
Carrot
Eggplant
Tomato
Potato
```

A version of the code that works:`wordcount_exercise.py`

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

input_file = "data/input/count_words.txt"

# 1 - Create pipelineOptions object to run the pipeline
beam_options = PipelineOptions(runner="DirectRunner")

# 2 - Apply transforms
# 2.1 - Read text from file
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
    lines = pipeline | beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file) | beam.Map(print)
```

Output :

```
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.6 interpreter.
Strawberry
Carrot
Eggplant
Tomato
Potato
```

A version of the code that does not work:`wordcount_exercise.py`

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

input_file = "data/input/count_words.txt"

# 1 - Create pipelineOptions object to run the pipeline
beam_options = PipelineOptions(runner="DirectRunner")

# 2 - Create the pipeline using the pipelineOptions
pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options)
# 3 - Apply transforms
# 3.1 - Read text from file
lines = pipeline | beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file) | beam.Map(print)
```

Nothing is output.

Why does the pipeline need to be declared within a `with` statement ? And why isn't it working with a simple declaration ?

Comment: I don't know for certain (never used apache_beam) but it seems possible that you only get the output once the pipeline is closed. That will happen implicitly when you use 'with'. Try adding pipeline.close() to the end of your second code fragment

Comment: try: ```pipeline.apply(pipeline | beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file) | beam.Map(print)) ```

Comment: @DarkKnight, pipeline does not have a close() method

Comment: @darthbaba I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work using `with`, why use `apply` instead?

Comment: *"pipeline does not have a close() method"* - Context managers ([i.e. `with` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)) call the `.__exit__()` method for you, not `.close()`. Try calling `.__exit__()` manually and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @Imad - I did say that I'd never used apache_beam and never suggested that calling close() was a definitive solution

Comment: @Tomalak, yes tried that, but it expects some more arguments. I'm reading up on how to use it :)

Comment: Context managers are used for the automatic setup and teardown of resources, __init__ is ran first and __enter__ then the code in the statement block and finally __exit__ which does the cleanup. So the base pipeline class initializes some objects start a subprocess in the __enter__ and applies transforms in the statement block and finally does a cleanup please refer to the code here 
 https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/pipeline.py

Comment: @Tomalak `__exit__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'exc_type', 'exc_val', and 'exc_tb'`

Comment: According to the source code linked above you can supply `None` to those arguments, they are optional.

Comment: @Tomalak, Indeed but I get `Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'Pipeline' object has no attribute '_extra_context'`

Comment: Oh well. In the end we can say: You need a `with` statement because Apache integrated those semantics tightly into the way their pipeline works. You could do it without a `with` statement if you would mimic perfectly they things the library does when `__exit__()` is called, but that would mean writing brittle, hard to follow, boilerplate code that depends on private library-internal implementation details - in short, it would be more work on top of being a Bad Idea.

Comment: @Tomalak, thanks for the tip, it does seem to be integrated that way by apache_beam. It was never my intention to use the pipeline this way, I just wanted to know why it didn't work :) your answer seems to point to the right direction.

Comment: `_extra_context` seems to be instanciated within the `def __enter__(self)` method, which I haven't called so it's normal (I guess) that I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipeline doesn't need a `with` statement, but adding it removes the need to manually run the pipeline with `pipeline.run()` ( or `p.run()` in some cases where you pipeline variable is `p`).

Similarly as opening files with a `with` that closes them automatically (`f.close()`), the `with` for `Pipeline()` uses `p.run()`.

For the code you posted, simply add `pipeline.run()` at the end.

Comment: I see the `__exit__` method has a `self.result = self.run()` within it, which is called when using `with` statement. But it has to be called manually otherwise. Thanks for the insight !